# Cannot cast int32 to int16. Int16 type value is too large or too small

Tags: vb.net, casting, overflowexception

I want to cast an Int32 value to Int16 value. Data lost when casting is not a problem to me. But a `System.OverflowException` says the Int16 type value is too large or too small.

```
Dim num As Int32 = &HFFFFFFF
Dim num2 As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(num)
Debug.WriteLine(num.ToString("X4"))
Debug.WriteLine(num2.ToString("X4"))
```

If I want to cast an Int32 &HFFFFFFF to &HFFFF so what should I do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've fixed your tag - `OverflowException` and `StackOverflowException` are *very* different.

Comment: You're getting the overflowException error because your int32 value is greater than Int16.MaxValue or less than Int16.MinValue.

Comment: IMO If I have to check limitation or using try..catch before casting, it would be not very nice since the code will longer.

Comment: `Dim num2 As Int16 = CShort(IIf((num And &HFFFF) < 32768, (num And &HFFFF), (num And &HFFFF) - 65536))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, as I said in my comment, that your casting is invalid because int16 has `maxValue` and `MinValue` which your int32 obviously does not sit in between.

Try the following to see your error more clearly:

```
 Debug.WriteLine(Int16.MaxValue.ToString)
 Debug.WriteLine(Int16.MinValue.ToString)
 Debug.WriteLine(num.ToString)
```

[image]

Your best workaround is to trim the last 4 F off your int32 whenever converting, if you still insist on doing it:

```
 Sub Main()
        Dim num As Int32 = &HFFFFFFF
        Dim num2 As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(num.ToString("X8").Substring(num.ToString("X8").Length - 4, 4), 16)
        Debug.WriteLine(num.ToString("X4"))
        Debug.WriteLine(num2.ToString("X4"))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Comment: It produces `FFFFFFF` and `68DB` since `ToString` prints decimal string by default and `Remove` is not quite reasonable here.
I correct the conversion to `Dim num2 As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(num.ToString("X8").Substring(num.ToString("X8").Length - 4, 4), 16)` and it works.
Thanks!

Comment: I will accept your answer if you can correct it to produce the right output. 1+ for the information

Comment: @QuangYen: There you go.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ignore `OverflowException` while casting and arithmetic operations (including division by zero) across entire your project, I'd suggest you set the compiler option [`/removeintchecks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/key2x70f.aspx).

> To set /removeintchecks in the Visual Studio integrated development
>   environment
>
> 1. Have a project selected in Solution Explorer. On the Project menu, click Properties. For more information, see Introduction to the Project Designer.
> 2. Click the Compile tab.
> 3. Click the Advanced button.
> 4. Modify the value of the Remove integer overflow checks box.

And, `Convert.ToInt16()` still generates the `OverflowException` regardless of that option. To benefit from that option, you can use `CType` or `CShort` instead.

```
Dim num As Int32 = &HFFFFFFF
Dim num2 As Int16 = CType(num, Int16)
Debug.WriteLine(num.ToString("X4"))
Debug.WriteLine(num2.ToString("X4"))
```